# Google Chrome on iPhone/iPad doesn't support downloading csv file and then save it to my device

Tags: ios, google-chrome-app

I want to download the csv/xlsx file and save it to my device (to Files app), it works on Safari which showing a confirm pop up to decide whether I want to View or Download it.

However, Google Chrome on iPhone doesn’t allow me to download the file, instead it’s opening the file right after I click on the download button. I have tried with a ZIP file and Chrome shows me an option to download this ZIP file and save it to my device.

I have prepared a shared folder for demonstrate my issue. Please go to [this](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1Xi5Z2l5tMhexcd0UkPCV0LOUUSHSPzvd) to see some screenshots and play around with downloading the files.

**My questions**:

1. Is this an issue on Chrome (for iPhone and iPad)?
2. Why is it behaving differently on CSV file and ZIP file?
3. Is there any way to let Chrome to show me the option to download CSV/EXCEL file and save it to my device (Files app)?

Device Info: Google Chrome (v80.0.3987.95) on iOS 13.3.1.

Thanks,
Josh

Comment: Hi Josh, did you get this issue sorted? Just wondering, as I have something similar to yours.